# Logic App Deployment - integration account cannot be found: The workflow must be associated with an integration account to use the workflow run action

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that was deploying from visual studio without issue a few weeks ago.
Today its throwing the following error on deployment:

```
17:27:10 -   "error": {
17:27:10 -     "code": "IntegrationAccountAssociationRequired",
17:27:10 -     "message": "The workflow must be associated with an integration account to use the     workflow run action 'Liquid transform' of type 'Liquid'."
17:27:10 -   }
```

Within my logic app, it has a parameter that references the integration account:

```
    "IntegrationAccountRef": {
  "type": "string",
  "minLength": 1,
  "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/99x99x9x-9xx9-x99x-x99x-x99x99x99x99/resourcegroups/devResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/devIntegrationAccount"
},
```

I also reference this parameter in the parameters section of the logic app resource, so the logic app knows its the integration account:

```
        "integrationAccount": {
      "id": "[parameters('IntegrationAccountRef')]"
    }
```

Yet it still throws the error mentioned at the top.
Has something changed in how Logic Apps now reference integration accounts in an arm template?

Appreciate any advice and expertise.

Comment: It seems your template is correct. May I know if you deploy the template to azure just after creating the integration account ? As we need to wait a few minutes after creating integration account, and then we can use it in logic app. So when you create the integration account, could you please wait a moment before you do the deployment ?

Comment: unfortunately not, the integration account has existed for many weeks.

Comment: Figured this out. even though i had set the reference to the Integration account in the code, it needs to be done in the logic app properties within visual studio.  

1. Click anyplace in the white space of the Visual Studio Logic App.

2. Look inside the Property Windows for the Integration Account selection windows.

3. Select the Integration Account you want to use and save your Logic App.

Comment: Could you please post the solution as an answer in "answer" area ?

Answer (score 1):

Just summarize the steps in your comments for other communities reference:

Even though we have set the reference to the integration account in the template code, it also needs to be done in the logic app properties within visual studio.

1. Click anyplace in the white space of the Visual Studio Logic App.
2. Look inside the Property Windows for the Integration Account selection windows.
3. Select the Integration Account you want to use and save your Logic App